# How to update couchbase inner-structured records?

Tags: couchbase, sql++

**Intro**

Hi everyone, Although I read the Couchbase documentation, it was unclear to me.
I want to update specific field's values in Couchbase. I can't figure out how to do this because the structure is a little it complex.

**The Structure**

```
"shops": {
    "1": {
      "workingHours": [
        {
          "interval": {
            "closed": 15,
            "open": 9
          },
          "info": {
            "name": xBurger,
            "location": London
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "closed": 18,
            "open": 8
          },
          "info": {
            "name": Pizzeria,
            "location": Venice
          }
        },
       ]
```

**NEEDS**

I need to change the open-closed hours.
If open-closed hour is 9-15 -> change it to 12-20
If open-closed hour is 8-18 -> change it to 10-16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it

```
UPDATE `your-bucket`
SET wh.interval.open = 12 FOR wh IN `your-bucket`.`shops`.`1`.`workingHours` WHEN (wh.interval.open = 9 AND wh.interval.closed = 15) END,
wh.interval.closed = 20 FOR wh IN `your-bucket`.`shops`.`1`.`workingHours` WHEN (wh.interval.open = 9   AND wh.interval.closed = 15) END,
wh.interval.open = 10 FOR wh IN `your-bucket`.`shops`.`1`.`workingHours` WHEN (wh.interval.open = 8     AND wh.interval.closed = 18) END,
wh.interval.closed = 16 FOR wh IN `your-bucket`.`shops`.`1`.`workingHours` WHEN (wh.interval.open = 8   AND wh.interval.closed = 18) END
```

just make sure to replace **your-bucket** with your real bucket name

Answer (score 1):

This will update all shops

```
INSERT INTO default VALUES("f001", { "shops": { "1": { "workingHours": [ { "interval": { "closed": 15, "open": 9 }, "info": { "name": "Burger", "location": "London" } }, { "interval": { "closed": 18, "open": 8 }, "info": { "name": "Pizzeria", "location": "Venice" } } ] }, "2": { "workingHours": [ { "interval": { "closed": 15, "open": 9 }, "info": { "name": "Burger", "location": "London" } }, { "interval": { "closed": 18, "open": 10 }, "info": { "name": "Pizzeria", "location": "Venice" } } ] } } });

UPDATE default AS d
SET wh.interval = OBJECT_CONCAT(wh.interval, {"open":12, "closed":20})
         FOR wh IN nv.workingHours
               FOR ns:nv IN d.shops
             WHEN wh.interval.open = 9 AND wh.interval.closed = 15 END,
   wh.interval = OBJECT_CONCAT(wh.interval, {"open":10, "closed":16})
         FOR wh IN nv.workingHours
               FOR ns:nv IN d.shops
             WHEN wh.interval.open = 8 AND wh.interval.closed = 18 END;
```